# Setting LinearLayout Background Resource scale type programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout

I have a linear layout that when i want programmatically to enter a TileXY background image to it i can do it that way:

```
ImageButton.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(Button1ImageURI));
Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(Button1ImageURI);
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, temp);
bitmapDrawable.SetTileModeXY(Shader.TileMode.Repeat, Shader.TileMode.Repeat);
MainLinearLayout.Background = bitmapDrawable;
```

I'm not sure how i can do the same but this time i want the **bitmapDrawable** to **ScaleType.FitCenter** in the **LinearLayout**.

I'm not sure how i can do that, if i don't put a **SetTileModeXY** in the **BitmapDrawable**, Background in **MainLinearLayout** is scaled with **FitXY**, 
but i want to be scaled in **FitCenter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you want to set image as background on the `LinearLayout`, when you can create `ImageView` as a child of the `LinearLayout` with width and height that match the parent(`LinearLayout`), and use the benefits of the `ImageView`. Setting the image as source and use the ScaleType?

Comment: I thought if Linear layout can do that cause what i want is still a simple linear layout background

Comment: Yes, but the background applies on the measurements of the element, so the purpose is to color the whole canvas which reasonably it will by default be fitXY :)